# Conditional image source with Vue based on boolean value

Tags: vue.js

I currently have my image tag set up like so:

```
<img v-if="highQuality" :src="post.data.url">
<img v-if="highQuality == false" :src="post.data.thumbnail">
```

As you can see the image src changes based on whether `highQuality` is true or false.

I have a select tag with the two bool options, if I start on false and change it to true it updates the images to high quality sources, but if I set it back to false it seems to stay on High quality. So I'm thinking that this is a bad attempt at a vue if conditional.

is there a more "Vue" like way of writing this?

edit: extra code

DOM

```
<select v-model="highQuality">
     <option value="true">High Quality</option>
     <option value="false">Low Resolution</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            highQuality: false,
            posts: [],
        },
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the select tag is properly changing the value of `highQuality`? Can you show some of its code?

Comment: @acdcjunior Its toggled with a select and its working because I tested it by modelling the value inside some text and its changing but its not changing the src URL. If I start at low quality and flick to hi quality it works but I cant switch back I have refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `<option>`s. `<select>` is assigning a string, not a boolean.

Don't use:

```
<option value="true">High Quality</option>
```

Use:

```
<option :value="true">High Quality</option>
```

Problematic:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    highQuality: false,
    posts: [],
    post: {data: {url: 'http://bc.id.au/images/fr_flag.gif', thumbnail: 'http://bc.id.au/images/de_flag.gif'}}
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="highQuality">
     <option value="true">High Quality</option>
     <option value="false">Low Resolution</option>
  </select>

  <img v-if="highQuality" :src="post.data.url">
  <img v-if="highQuality == false" :src="post.data.thumbnail">
</div>
```

Fixed:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    highQuality: false,
    posts: [],
    post: {data: {url: 'http://bc.id.au/images/fr_flag.gif', thumbnail: 'http://bc.id.au/images/de_flag.gif'}}
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="highQuality">
     <option :value="true">High Quality</option>
     <option :value="false">Low Resolution</option>
  </select>

  <img v-if="highQuality" :src="post.data.url">
  <img v-if="highQuality == false" :src="post.data.thumbnail">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `highQuality == false` condition is failing, are you sure you're setting `highQuality` to exactly `false`?

You needn't duplicate the tag, just do this instead:

```vue
<img :src="highQuality ? post.data.url : post.data.thumbnail">
```